# Force RStudio to use anaconda python 3.5

Tags: python, r, macos, rstudio, anaconda

I have some python scripts (python 3.5 based) which I want to call using R/RStudio. For the same, I am using `rPython`package. Whenever I make a call to these scripts, RStudio uses python 2.7.10 as shown

```
   import sys
print(sys.version)
2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

but I want to use python 3.5.
On my system, python 3.5 is installed and is set to default as shown below

```
HaroonMacBook:~ haroonr$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I tried to force python 3.5 in RStudio by using:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/Users/haroonr/anaconda/bin",Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=":"))
```

Accordingly, I do get

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/Users/haroonr/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin"
```

What all are the other ways to force Rstudio for using python 3.5

### UPDATE 1:

I call python code using following statements from RStudio:

```
library(rPython)
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/Users/haroonr/anaconda/bin",Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=":"))
python.load("/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/Users/haroonr/Desktop/demo2.py", get.exception = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you're making the call to Python from Rstudio?

Comment: @Jonathan  added programming lines as UPDATE1.